# Cannot import a function from Lambda Layers AWS

Tags: python, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

Trying to deploy a scraper on AWS. I am importing the following structure as a layer into `lambda` after zipping

```
lambdalayer (folder)
:- python   ( folder)
         :- covid.py (file to run)
         :- lib
               :- python3.8
                           :-site-pakcages
                                          :- All dependencies
```

I have tried many variations of this and tried moving the file to different folders, but `lambda` is not able to import `covid.py`.
Here is the `lambda` code.

```
import boto3
import json
from covid import scrapeGlobalCase


def lambda_handler(event,context):
    print(os.environ['PYTHONPATH'])
    s3 =boto3.resource('s3')
    print("Request Covid Data..")
    cov_case = scrapeGolbalCase()
    BUCKET_NAME='seleniumbucket43'
    DATE=f"{cov_case['date']}"
    OUTPUT_NAME = f'dataKeyTest{DATE}.json'
    OUTPUT_BODY = json.dumps(cov_case)
    print("Sending to S3")
    S3.bucket(BUCKET_NAME).put_object(Key=OUTPUT_NAME,Body=OUTPUT_BODY)
    print(f'Job done at {DATE}')
```

Error: -

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'covid'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "stackTrace": []
}
```

`covid.py` file

```
import requests,datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def scrapeGlobalCase():
    try:
        url = "https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/"
        req = requests.get(url)
        bsObj = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "html.parser")
        data = bsObj.find_all("div",class_ = "maincounter-number")
        NumConfirmed = int(data[0].text.strip().replace(',', ''))
        NumDeaths = int(data[1].text.strip().replace(',', ''))
        NumRecovered = int(data[2].text.strip().replace(',', ''))
        NumActive = NumConfirmed - NumDeaths - NumRecovered
        TimeNow = datetime.datetime.now()
        return {
            'date': str(TimeNow),
            'ConfirmedCases': NumConfirmed,
            'ActiveCases': NumActive,
            'RecoveredCases': NumRecovered,
            'Deaths': NumDeaths
         }
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

p = scrapeGlobalCase()
print(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the formatting on your zip file may be incorrect.  Follow the instructions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html#configuration-layers-compile).  You can also test unzipping your lamba layer and verifying you're not including the "lambdalayer" folder.

```
python/covid.py
python/requests
....
```

It should not include the site packages path, only the files and folders inside site packages.  Here's [another example](https://wahlnetwork.com/2020/07/28/how-to-create-aws-lambda-layers-for-python/).

Comment: No, It doesn't work. Basically zip everything in 1 folder called python..right?..That doesn't work.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't see the folder at all in the layer.